# Errors with building meteor package

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I costomized bootstrap.js with only what i need, after i have to build package, because if add it in libs or on client, console browser writes me

```
You have to add a Bootstrap package, i.e. meteor add `twbs:bootstrap`
```

And i don't want to use this package, it's too large.
I started to build my own package, my `package.js`

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');
  api.use('jquery',['web.browser','client','server']);
  api.addFiles('zboot.js');
});
```

`bootstrap.js` has dependency on `jquery`, but i still have some errors

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Package (packages/fleple:zboot/zboot.js:1:1)
```

What should i do? Please suggest

Comment: Looks like you might need to export `jQuery`. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_export

Comment: Jquery by default in meteor packages, i solved the problem by adding api.addFiles('zboot.js','web.browser');